# actualizar el valor de una key con mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

como haría para actualizar el valor de un campo en una BD mongodb de esta manera: cada usuario tiene un Array de autos, cada auto tiene una placa y un campo que representa el numero de galones en el tanque, dado el siguiente modelo:

```
User{
"name": String
cars:[
   {
     plate:String
     gas: Number
   }

 ]
}
```

Como sería la función para actualizar el campo gas?, actualmente trato de hacerlo así:

```
export const addGas = async (userId, carPlate, gas) => {
    const user = await externalUser.findById(userId);
    let cars = user.cars;
    let carToUpdate;

    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (cars[i].plate === carPlate) carToUpdate = cars[i];
    }
    let newGas = carToUpdate.gas + gas;
    const result = externalUser.updateOne(
        { _id: userId },
        { $set: { cars: { carToUpdate: { gas: newGas } } } }
    );
    return result;
};
```

Este método no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más fácil es acceder al `_id` directo del arreglo de `cars` de esta manera:

```js
export const addGas = async(userId, carPlate, gas) => {
  const user = await externalUser.findById(userId);
  user.cars.id(id_del_carro).gas += gas
  
  
  return user.save();
};
```

Bajo esta estructura deberás mandar un parámetro que contenga el id del carro. No es necesario hacer nada más para que aparezca puesto que mongodb siempre lo genera ( a menos que le digas lo contrario). La operación `save` solo modificara aquellos valores que hayan cambiado.

Para hacerlo con `update` sería algo así:

```js
export const addGas = async(userId, carPlate, gas) => {
  return externalUser.update({
    "_id": userId,
    "cars._id": id_de_carro
  }, {
    $inc: {
      "cars.$.gas": gas
    }
  })
};
```

El operador `.$` es un localizador para los arreglos.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i-9Ae25bwaP).

Answer (score 1):

Ya te han dado una muy buena respuesta que te ayuda a resolver el problema. Yo aportaré algo adicional.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar el campo de un documento que se encuentra dentro de un Array de documentos en MongoDB. La actualización supone el incremento de un valor numérico en dicho campo.

Uno de los problemas de la forma en que lo intentas es la atomicidad de la operación. Cuando tratamos con bases de datos, debemos procurar mantener siempre la consistencia de los datos usando operaciones atómicas.

Otro problema es que desaprovechas las herramientas de Mongoose (y de MongoDB) para hacer el trabajo, y tratas de aplicar una lógica un poco confusa para tratar de resolver el problema planteado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para esta operación de actualización, en la que dispones del valor `_id` del documento que deseas actualizar, el valor de `placa` que identifica un subdocumento de la lista y el valor de `gas` que será incrementado en el campo del mismo nombre, puedes usar sin problemas el método `helper` del Modelo llamado [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), el cual [realizará una operación atómica](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#atomic-updates) sobre el documento. Puedes leer más [en la documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#how-to-use-findoneandupdate-in-mongoose).

Además, tal como se indica en la otra respuesta, para acceder a un elemento de la lista (Array) de coches, sin importar su posición en la misma (y sin que tengas que recorrerla manualmente) debes usar el [operador de posición](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#mongodb-update-up.-) que, según indica la documentación:

> El operador posicional `$` identifica un elemento para actualizar en un Array sin especificar explícitamente la posición del elemento en el Array.

Con esto en mente debemos escribir la sentencia de actualización o el objeto de actualización de la consulta. En este caso se desea incrementar el valor del campo `gas` de un elemento particular de la lista de coches.

Para poder usar el operador posicional (`$`), el campo de tipo Array debe aparecer necesariamente en la consulta, de lo contrario MongoDB nos devolverá un mensaje de error. Por lo tanto la sentencia de actualización debe incluir un campo de tipo Array para la búsqueda o match y un operador de actualización de un elemento de dicho Array en el objeto de actualización, usando el operador posicional. Por ejemplo:

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
   { <array>: value ... }, // <- búsqueda o match
   { <update operator>: { "<array>.$" : value } } // <- actualización
)
```

La consulta de actualización la podemos escribir de la siguiente forma:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: ObjectId(userId), cars.plate: carPlate },
  { $inc: { "cars.$.gas": gas },  // <- usamos " para encerrar el nombre del campo a ser actualizado
  { new: true }, // <- opción para devolver el documento actualizado
);
```

En esta consulta he agregado la opción `new: true` para indicar que dese obtener el documento una vez que se ha realizado la actualización, de lo contrario MongoDB devuelve por defecto el documento encontrado antes de realizar la actualización.

Por último, cabe destacar que todos los métodos `helper` de los Modelos de Mongoose, para realizar operaciones CRUD, devuelven un objeto de tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), y no una Promesa (parece que hay mucha confusión sobre este tema). [Las `Queries` no son Promesas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises), y aunque ofrecen soporte para usar `then` y `await`, su comportamiento no es el mismo que una Promesa. Para obtener realmente una Promesa de una Query, debemos usar el método `exec(https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec)`.

Dicho esto, una forma de escribir el método `addGas` sería la siguiente:

```js
export const addGas = async (userId, carPlate, gas) => {
  const filter = {
    _id: userId,
    "cars.plate": carPlate,  // <- nombre de campo entre " para usar notación de punto
  }

  const update = {
    $inc: { "cars.$.gas": gas },
  }

  const options = {
    new: true,
  }
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options).exec();
    return updatedUser;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error("Error updating user");
    return;
  }
};
```

Notemos dos cosas: he utilizado `try / catch`, ya que al usar `async / await` sobre Promesas, es necesario usar `try / catch` para capturar cualquier rechazo de la Promesa. Por otro lado, la llamada a `findOneAndUpdate` la hago directamente sobre el Modelo de datos. Es posible que tengas implementada alguna abstracción del modelo de datos según observo en tu código:

```js
const user = await externalUser.findById(userId);
```

Si este fuera el caso, bastaría con agregar un método propio a dicha abstracción que recibiera los mismos parámetros que recibe el `helper` de Mongoose y devolver el resultado de dicha operación. Toma en cuenta que el método `exec()` se usaría del lado de la abstracción y no en tu método `addGas`. Si el método a implementar en dicha abstración también es de tipo `async`, significa que devolverá una Promesa. Si el manejo de la excepción lo haces del lado de la abstracción, no sería necesario usar `try / catch` en el método `addGas`, de lo contrario, debes usarlo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y aclare las dudas que podrías tener al respecto.